# Postgres query to create combinations

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this -

**tableCountry**

1. USA
2. UK
3. Germany

I want to write a query to list out the following combinations -

```
>USA-UK
>USA-Germany
>UK-USA
>UK-Germany
>Germany-USA
>Germany-UK
```

Is such a combination listing possible through postgresql?

Thanks.

Comment: Readers will also want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/31175335/398670 which is a follow-up of this one.

Answer (score 2):

This is as simple as:

```
SELECT t1.Country || '-' || t2.Country
  FROM table t1
  JOIN table t2 ON t1.Country <> t2.Country;
```