# Complex Postgres query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a db schema like following -

```
(Country table)
| Country | Country Code| 
-------------------------
    ABC         A 
    BCD         B
```

(Organization Table)

### |Organization | Country Code | Organization Code

```
Org 1            A                O1
Org 2            B                O2
Org 3            A                O3
```

(Transaction Table)

### | Organization | Export(in $) | Import(in $)|

```
 O1             X1                Y1
 O2             X2                Y2
 O3             X3                Y3
```

I want the result set to be like this  -

```
| Corridor | Total Export | Total Import |
------------------------------------------
  ABC-BCD      X1+X2+X3       Y1+Y2+Y3
```

Corridor column should be the combination of all the countries in the Country table.

How can I form a query to implement this logic? Thanks

Comment: How do you define the field Corridor? Is it the combination of all the countries or only the 1st two countries or what?

Comment: Corridor column should be the combination of all the countries in the Country table.

Comment: What do you mean by "a combination of all the countries in the Country table"? Do you mean each country combination has one entry? What does each row in your result set represent?

Comment: Incidentally, the question title "Complex Postgres query" is not very specific. I don't think your query is likely to be particularly complex, but you might do better to highlight what about it is giving you most trouble. Is it the many-many table join? Summing totals? Defining the question?

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to run an aggregate query:

```
select sum(t.export) as TotalExport,
sum(t.import) as TotalImport
FROM country c inner join Organization o on c.Country_Code = o.Country_Code
inner join Transaction t on o.organization_code = t.organization_code
```

Now, you ask: where is the Corridor column? The answer is: use the [string_agg](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES) function:

```
select string_agg(DISTINCT c.country, '-' ORDER BY c.country) as Corridor,
sum(t.export) as TotalExport,
sum(t.import) as TotalImport
FROM country c inner join Organization o on c.Country_Code = o.Country_Code
inner join Transaction t on o.organization_code = t.organization_code
```